# Enable edit of tableview with Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, tableview, edit

I would like to make a table view editable, i.e. you click edit and it gives you the option to delete entries. My understanding is that Apple makes this easy with the following code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return NO;
}
```

I had this working when my table was in a mutable array, however since I shifted to Core Data and NSFetchedResults controller, while it shows the edit button on the upper left and also gives you a done button after you click edit, the table is not editable.

Is something special needed for Core Data or what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you subclassed UIViewController, rather than UITableViewController?  If so, you need to implement `setEditing:animated:` and specifically put your table view into editing mode - something like `[self.myTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated]`

Comment: Yes, am subclassing UIViewController.  Where do I put this?

Comment: Ok.  Got it to work with - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];  Many thanks.
}

Comment: No problem.  Presumably you also have `commitEditingStyle` to do the actual delete.

Comment: Yes this was here from swipetodelete.

Comment: Whoops.  Glitch has popped up.  Works fine on own.  However, when I click on row in tableview to view detail and then go back to tableview, it is in edit mode i.e. there are red edit dashes to left of row but Barbutton says edit.  You have to click on Edit and it changes to Done. Then when you click on Done it goes back to normal...Arghh

Comment: Fixed issue.  Had to delete method leftover from previous attempt to get this to work.